# calling another view internally without the usage of button in an iphone app

Tags: iphone

I have searched a lot but i could not be able to find a way to call a another view without the usage of button in an iphone app.

For eg. I have a code running on processing camera frame in which a condition returns true or false. what i want is that as soon as condition returns true app should open another view and close down the camera preview view.

Sorry for asking such a silly question but i am very new to iphone development

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am sure that the following works in iOS versions prior to iOS 5 and if you have a NavigationController :

```
MyNewViewController* boo = [[MyNewViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyNewViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:boo animated:NO];
[boo release];
```

I don't know how to do it otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

**what i understand is you want to remove current view and just after that load a new view based on condition.**

if that is ..
Check this

- in Xcode ..start a **utility(template)** project
- Check the `show info` method ...put a breakpoint.
- in the flip side View ..check the back button action..the one with
  this type of statement   `self.delegate Flip.....` put a breakpoint
  there too..
- now run the app.. press back on flip side view..you will follow along
  that your main view gets notified about its dismissal..so you can add your code to load new view in that function..

**The moral is you should learn delegates..major feature of Objective-C**

**Edit :**

Performing method automatically without user interaction

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
 [self performSelector:@selector(ShowNewView) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.5]; // 1.5 seconds
[super viewDidLoad];
}


- (void)ShowNewView
{
NewView *view = [NewView alloc] ........ Your code
}
```

Comment: yes you are right but thing is that i dont want to use a button to do a flip i.e it should be done programatically not on user interaction

Comment: that is also easy.. just call this method based on timer..which will fire like say after 15 sec..look up NSTimer class in the docs

Comment: please if you can give some code snippet for that coz i am really stuck in there.

Comment: which method you are talking about?

Comment: this is what I am doing `- (void)goToWebSite
{
        WebViewController *controller = [[[WebViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"WebViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
        controller.delegate = self;
        controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
        [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
    }` I am getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS when i call this function in another function at `[self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];`

Comment: yes..you will get an error since there is no controller in the other function.. did you check my code.. in your example in another function you have to call `[self goToWebSite]` instead of self present...

Comment: yes and i am calling `[self goTOWebSite]` in another function but when program executes this function then i get this error in `goTOWebSite` function on line `[self present...`

Comment: then the error is something else..accept this answer and post this question with appropriate code in a new question..you will get more help in a new question.since this sues is quite old now